# How do I allow a function to be called by two names?

Tags: python, function

For example, I have a function, let's say `alert()`. I want the function to also work if someone calls `alert_user()`, both having the same functionality. I imagine it to be something like this:

```
@synonym alert_user
def alert():
    print('hi!')
```

And it would work like this:

```
>>> alert()
hi!
>>> alert_user()
hi!
```

Is there such a thing?

Comment: I think this goes against Python's philosophy "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."

Comment: @WaleedKhan: That is true, but there can be legitimate reasons to do this (notably, if you make changes to an API but need to retain old names for backward compatibility during a transitional period, before the old names are removed).

Comment: define `alert_user` like this : `def alert_user():alert()`.

Answer (score 9):

A decorator (as in your example) does not have access to the enclosing namespace, so it can't create a new name for the thing it decorates.  However, it's easy to add an alias for your function:

```
def alert():
    print('hi!')
alert_user = alert
```

Comment: `raw_input = input` will make `raw_input()` available in Python 3.

Comment: If this is needed for some reason, this would be the best way to do it

Answer (score 3):

This will give you what you want

```
def alert():
    print('hi!')

alert_user = alert

>>> alert()
hi!
>>> alert_user()
hi!
```

Answer (score 2):

Function is the first level citizen in python.
Just add `alert_user = alert`.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above by fellow helpers you can define alert as a function then give alert a variable representation.

```
alert_user = alert
```

Thanks
Ben